# Modify an integer in MySQL Table using PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I've setup a MySQL database to keep track of inventory. So far, it's working well and consists of 3 pages. The first page (basic html) prompts the user to scan or enter a bar code number and hit enter.

The second page(.php) take the information entered, finds the matching bar code in the MySQL table, and returns the row (barcode, description, quantity) in a table. The third page is pretty much just a redirect to the first page so I can search a new item with ease.

This already works well for finding inventory, but I need to be able to modify the quantity of the row. Can this be achieved by adding a "modify" form under the returned table on page 2, and sending the number entered to a php script on page 3, or am I way off base?

I guess my main question would be, how do I go about adding or subtracting from the quantity value instead of just updating the cell with a new value.

Currently, page 2 looks something like this:

```
 <?php 
//Table
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px green;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Barcode</th><th>Description</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
function __construct($it) {
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
}

function current() {
    return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid green;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
}

function beginChildren() {
    echo "<tr>";
}

function endChildren() {
    echo "</tr>" . "\n";
}
} 
//Connection Info
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "XXXX";
$password = "XXXX";
$dbname = "foo";


//Connection Started, Data pulled
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,     $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE Barcode LIKE :barcode");
$paramBinding = "%" . $_POST["find"] . "%";
$stmt->bindParam(':barcode', $paramBinding);

$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v;
    }
}

//Error Check

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

//Kill Connection 
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>

</br> 
Modify Quantity:
</br> 
(input positive number to be added to stock or negative number to        subtract from stock) 
</br>
<form name="Modify" action="Redirect.php">
<input type="text" name="modify">
<input type="submit" value="Modify">
```

Mega-thanks in advance!

Comment: There aren't any rules for how to do this. Just do it however you wish as long as you can understand it in 6 months from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently working on a similar project and yes you seem to be on the right track. My strategy for this would be as follows:

1. A item is scanned and the data is extracted from the database.
2. There is a "Modify" button to click.
3. When the button is clicked a form is filled with the current data. I have been working to extract that data from the html table rather than going back to the database. I have been using jQuery for this.
4. The update query is sent when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks! That's and interesting method, hadn't thought about doing it that way. I've been trying (unsuccessfully so far) to pull the barcode from the first page, adding the quantity from the second page, and moving them into the php of the third page to find the matching barcode and modifying the quantity of that row.